# Knock out Drop Down - Using Bool Values

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am working on a drop down control that is powered by Boolean values.  I have a viewmodel that consists of the lookup dataset array (values and text attributes) and also a dataset that contains a Boolean value that needs to be aligned with that value chosen in the array.  So data in the viewmodel represents an actual data item, while lookupdata represents essentially a mapping of value pairs.  These two items really need to stay independent of eachother for the purposes of each data item containing only information relevant to it.

I have been able to get a sample working where I brought IsActive outside of the data object as it exists in viewmodel and placed it in viewmodel, however I can't get it to work while it is inside of viewmodel.  I have created a JSFiddle that demonstrates functionally what I want the user to see, as well as one where I have the data where it belongs, but the drop down does not work as expected.

Active maps to true and Inactive maps to false.  Switching between those should also affect the word true/false on the screen.

http://jsfiddle.net/rodearly/xF78A/11/

```
<div data-bind="with: data">
<select data-bind="options: $root.lookupData.status, optionsText: 'text', optionsValue: 'value', value: IsActive"></select>
<label>Value: </label>
<span data-bind="text: IsActive"></span>
</div>

<div>Alternative</div>
<div>
<select data-bind="options: lookupData.status, optionsText: 'text', optionsValue: 'value', value: IsActive"></select>
<label>Value: </label>
<span data-bind="text: IsActive"></span>
</div>

function Item(id, name) {
this.id = ko.observable(id);
this.name = ko.observable(name);
}

function getLookupData() {
var lookupData = {};
lookupData.status = [{
    text: "Active",
    value: true
}, {
    text: "Inactive",
    value: false
}];

return lookupData;
}


CreateImplantEditViewModel = function (data, lookupData) {
var vm = {};

vm.data = ko.observable(data);

vm.IsActive = ko.observable(false);

vm.lookupData = {};
vm.lookupData.status = ko.observableArray(lookupData.status);

return vm;
};

debugger;

var editImplantVm = CreateImplantEditViewModel({
    IsActive: false
},
getLookupData());

ko.applyBindings(editImplantVm);
```

Thanks for any help,

~David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here actually is that the Boolean values are being converted into string values.  To get this to work, value needs to be either a string or a number.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are attempting to do, your problem lies in the data that you are passing in to the 'CreateImplantEditViewModel' constructor. You need to create IsActive as an observable, otherwise it will never update:

```
var editImplantVm = CreateImplantEditViewModel({
    IsActive: ko.observable(false)
},
getLookupData());
```

I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xF78A/28/), and both dropdowns now update their associated text binding when you change the selected option.